# Send SignalR notification from other process

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have an architectural question with signalR

Let's say I have a web app (pure front JS) that use a web api and the web app query an API that do a long task and want to be notified when the task is finished.
So the web api create a fire and forget task, and we use SSE with signalR to notify the web app. It's working. Great, thanks to signalR.

But now, I want the long task to be run in another process, let's say with a msmq based system.
So, the web app query the API, the web api create a message, and the msmq service process the message asynchronously.

Can the msmq service hosted in another process (maybe another machine !) notify the web app that the task is finished ? It can be possible to put the connection id in the message, but the service can be able to send the notification ?

Comment: I think the simplest solution would be to expose api function like api/notify and then your msmq service would just call this function. Then api (backend for your web app) would use signalr to forward this message to your web app?

Comment: Why not. That means other process can't use the hub created in the web app

Answer (score 0):

I would use a servicebus, you can then use this library to forward the message directly to the clients.

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy

Comment: Hi anders, I don't see how to use your library. Note, I already use NSB as service bus

Comment: You create proxy that forwards your service bus messages, https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki/Handle-events-server-side. You can offcourse do this with vanilla signalr. But my library is doign all the plumbing