# How can detect receive message sent from another backend on signalR

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I want to know how my message can be received from another application. My scenarios is backend Admin will be send msg to BE client and vice versace !
Here is my description and the results below.
Project structure:

Project.Common

Project.BussinessLogic

Projec.AdminPortal (api https://localhost:7240)

Projec.ClientPortal (api https://localhost:7150)

Now Admin and client are 2 different api sets but share BL and common. I added a hub in the common project. I tried sending message like this at controller login from admin

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] UserLoginDto userLoginDto)
     {
         await SubmissionEventHub.SendMessageToAdmin("Send from admin Hello, Client!");
         var userLogged = await _authService.Authenticate(userLoginDto);
         return Ok(CustomResponseDto<UserLoggedDto>.SuccessResponse(StatusCodes.Status201Created,userLogged));
     }
```

```
public class SubmissionEventHub : Hub
     {
         private static HubConnection _adminConnection;
         private static HubConnection _clientConnection;
         private static HubConnection _trConnection;

         public async Task ReceiveMessage(string message)
         {
             await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
         }

         #region Admin
         public static async Task ConnectToAdminHub()
         {
             _adminConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                 .WithUrl("https://localhost:7240/submissionEventHub")
                 .Build();

             _adminConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
             {
                 Log.Information($"Received alert message from app Admin: {message}");
             });

             await _adminConnection.StartAsync();
         }

         public static async Task SendMessageToAdmin(string message)
         {
             if (_adminConnection == null)
             {
                 await ConnectToAdminHub();
             }

             await _adminConnection.InvokeAsync("SendMessageToAdmin", message);
         }
         #endregion

         #region Client
         public static async Task ConnectToClientHub()
         {
             _clientConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                 .WithUrl("https://localhost:7150/submissionEventHub")
                 .Build();

             _clientConnection.On<string>("ReceiveMessage", (message) =>
             {
                 Log.Information($"Received alert message from app Client: {message}");
             });

             await _clientConnection.StartAsync();
         }

         public static async Task SendMessageToClient(string message)
         {
             if (_clientConnection == null)
             {
                 await ConnectToClientHub();
             }

             await _clientConnection.InvokeAsync("ReceiveMessage", message);
         }
         #endregion
```

Admin program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
app.MapHub<SubmissionEventHub>("/submissionEventHub");
```

Client program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
app.MapHub<SubmissionEventHub>("/submissionEventHub");
await SubmissionEventHub.ConnectToAdminHub();
```

But I only see the log on admin console. expectation must be client console. May I missing something ?
[image]

Comment: Maybe the servicebus mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36571355/18789859) can meet your needs.

Comment: [Could you check the code is useful you or not?](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SXZOen)

Comment: Actually I fixed problem by send msg from admin app. And connect from client app to admin url. Tks for any suggest